# How to get substring of string using starting and ending character in PHP?

Tags: php

I am looking for finding middle part of a string using starting tag and ending tag in **PHP**.

```
$str = 'Abc/hello@gmail.com/1267890(A-29)';
$agcodedup = substr($str, '(', -1);
$agcode = substr($agcodedup, 1);
```

final expected value of `agcode`:

```
$agcode = 'A-29';
```

Comment: Need to get string between "(" and ")"  . Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use preg_match

```
    $str = 'Abc/hello@gmail.com/1267890(A-29)';
    if(  preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $string, $match ) ) echo $match[1]."\n\n";
```

Outputs

```
   A-29
```

You can check it out here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b6aa0bf9725b62b87b94edbccc2df1d73450ee4

Basically Regular expression says:

- start match, matches `\(` Open Paren literal
- capture group `( .. )`
- match everything except `[^)]+` Close Paren `)`
- end match, matches `\)` Close Paren literal

Oh and if you really have your heart set on `substr` here you go:

```
$str = 'Abc/hello@gmail.com/1267890(A-29)';

//this is the location/index of the ( OPEN_PAREN
//strlen 0 based so we add +1 to offset it
$start = strpos( $str,'(') +1;
//this is the location/index of the ) CLOSE_PAREN.
$end = strpos( $str,')');
//we need the length of the substring for the third argument, not its index
$len = ($end-$start);  

echo substr($str, $start, $len );
```

Ouputs

```
A-29
```

And you can test this here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88723be11fc82d88316d32a522030b149a4788aa

If it was me, I would benchmark both methods, and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

May this helps to you.

```
function getStringBetween($str, $from, $to, $withFromAndTo = false)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));

    if ($withFromAndTo) {
        return $from . substr($sub,0, strrpos($sub,$to)) . $to;
    } else {
        return substr($sub,0, strrpos($sub,$to));
    }

    $inputString = "Abc/hello@gmail.com/1267890(A-29)";
    $outputString = getStringBetween($inputString, '(', ')');

    echo $outputString; 
    //output will be A-29

    $outputString = getStringBetween($inputString, '(', ')', true);
    echo $outputString; 
    //output will be (A-29)


    return $outputString;
}
```